# A simple question from ANOVA

Tags: self-study, anova, random-variable, ratio

As per definition of $F$ statistic, $F= \frac{MST}{MSE}$ where MST and MSE denote mean square due to treatment and error respectively. From this definition of $F$ am I right in saying that $F$ increases with decrease in variability due to chance (error) and decrease with decrease in variability between groups (treatment).

My question stems from the confusion that if a random variable $Z$ is a ratio of two other random variables, then, can I say a similar relation as mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the assumptions of a simple one-way ANOVA model, when the Mean Square due to Treatment increases, this leads to a decrease in the Mean Square due to Error and an increase in corresponding $F$-statistic (since $MST+MSE = MS  Total$).

However, a ratio of any two random variables does not necessarily follow an $F$ distribution. The $F$ distribution is formed by taking the ratio of two independent $\chi^2$ random-variables, divided by their degrees of freedom. It just so happens from the Normality assumption of the ANOVA (and the centering and squaring of terms) that the ratio of $MST$ and $MSE$ follows an $F$ distribution.

That being said, in general, if you have any ratio, $Z=X/Y$, then $Z$ increases if $X$ increases while $Y$ remains unchanged and $Z$ decreases if $Y$ increases while $X$ remains unchanged.

See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution for more details on $F$ distribution.

Comment: So, is it wrong to say that F stat increases with decrease in variability due to chance if nothing about the error due to treatments is mentioned?

Comment: In single-factor ANOVA, if there is a "decrease in variability due to chance" this implies that the $MSE$ decreases, which in turn implies an increase in $MST$, and this implies an increase in the $F$-statistic. In SINGLE factor when $MSE$ increases, $MST$ decreases, since the two values are linked via the formula $MSTotal=MSE+MST$ as I stated above. You cannot increase one without decreasing the other and vice versa.

Comment: So the number of factors is to be taken into consideration. In a case where number of factors is unknown, or more than one, nothing can be said. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the number of factors is to be taken into consideration.  For what purpose?  If you have another factor, say Treatment 2, then in a two-way anova, the $MSE = MSTotal-MSTreatment_1-MSTreament_2-InteractionEffects$

Comment: I meant, is this relation between mse and F obeyed only in a single factor case?

Comment: @user46697, the relationship becomes more complex for added treatment or added covariates.  See my previous comment for example.  You'll see $MSE$ in a two-factor study is determined by taking the total variability ($MSTotal$), removing the variability from both treatments and their interaction effects (i.e. $MST_1$, $MST_2$, and $MST_1 \times MST_2$).

The bottom line is that the $F$-test for any treatment depends on only two things:  the numerator $MST$ and denominator $MSE$.  By modifying either of these two, you alter the magnitude for the $F$-statistic.

Comment: It seems to depend on number of groups . The MST depends on number of groups or variables and MSE depends on number of observations across several groups.Why and what is  the confusion. The numerator uses k-samples theory and denominator simply estimates overall  average (population average) of the sampling error variance. The ratio generates F statistics. The change in number of groups or variables affects the magnitude of F.